# How to configure ABP Framework to use Bootswatch in RTL languages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, abp

With a reference to [Jonathan Potts ABP Bootswatch article](https://github.com/jonathanpotts/AbpBootswatchDemo) there is a clear and good approach to switching `Bootstrap` with `Bootswatch` in ABP Framework. However, it is not working when it comes to using `Bootswatch` in RTL languages like **Arabic** or **Farsi**.

**I wonder what am I missing and what is the best practice to solve this problem?**

Project's UI is based on `MVC Razor Pages`

Here is my BundleContributor:

```
public class BootswatchStyleContributor : BundleContributor
{
    public override void ConfigureBundle(BundleConfigurationContext context)
    {
        var theme = "minty";

        var bootstrap = "/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css";
        var bootswatch = $"/libs/bootswatch/{theme}/bootstrap.css";

        context.Files.ReplaceOne(bootstrap, bootswatch);
    }
}
```

And Configuration:

```
private void ConfigureBundles()
{
    Configure<AbpBundlingOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.StyleBundles.Configure(
            BasicThemeBundles.Styles.Global,
            bundle =>
            {
                bundle.AddFiles("/global-styles.css");
                bundle.AddContributors(typeof(BootswatchStyleContributor));
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Here is the result in LTR which is working fine:

[image: Works fine with LTR]

But not work after changing the language to an RTL language such as Arabic:

[image: Not works with RTL]

Comment: I guess Bootswatch is not currently supporting RTL. See https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/issues/1116 .

Comment: @EngincanVeske Actually, I found an open source project [Bootswatch-rtl](https://github.com/mrjelveh/bootswatch-rtl), but I'm not sure if it is a good idea to use it in ABP or not. I am still contemplating and playing around.

Comment: I didn't try it but it looks promising, if you give it a try maybe you can use the `CultureHelper.IsRtl` to check the current culture and replace the related css and js files if it's currently RTL language. (https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Packages/Volo/Abp/AspNetCore/Mvc/UI/Packages/Bootstrap/BootstrapStyleContributor.cs#L11-L18)

Answer (score 0):

i used @Engincan idea
using CultureHelper.IsRtl is fine

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33420098)